# Insert a row from 1 table to another which are not in first table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

```
  ID    Date        Time          Status    UserID

  1  2017-02-23   19:30:00.0000000  1      130
  2  2017-02-23   20:00:00.0000000  0      130
```

The above table is a #temptable.This is executing in different intervals.So on executing ,first 2 rows are inserted in the below table

```
     Date       Time            Status
    2017-02-23  19:30:00.0000000    1
    2017-02-23  20:00:00.0000000    0
```

Then executing ,1 row is added to the #temptable as below.

```
     ID    Date        Time           Status    UserID

  1  2017-02-23   19:30:00.0000000  1      130
  2  2017-02-23   20:00:00.0000000  0      130
  3  2017-02-23   23:30:00.0000000  1      130
```

So I need to insert the new row from the #temptable to the below table which is not in the below table

```
        Date        Time            Status
    2017-02-23  19:30:00.0000000    1
    2017-02-23  20:00:00.0000000    0
```

Comment: Try using "except"... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
insert into belowTable 
select Date,Time,Status from #TempTable 
except
select Date,Time,Status from belowTable
```